# For Loop in batch fail to work with user input as condition

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, user-input

I am trying to use For Loops that will start and end based on values entered by user in batch. However, when using the user input variables, the loop fail to work. May I know what have I done wrong and how do I correct it? Thanks in advance!

*P.S. I have tried both `!` and `%`*

Here's the my source code which shows the for loop which is having problem:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /p sy="Enter start year (e.g. 2020): "
set /p sm="Enter start month (e.g. 08): "
set /p ey="Enter end year (e.g. 2020): "
set /p em="Enter end month (e.g. 08): "
echo ***LIST OF MISSING FILES FROM %sm% %sy% to %em% %ey%*** > checkFile_%SUBFILENAME%.txt

for /L %%y in (%sy%,1,%ey%) do (
    for /L %%m in (1,1,%maxMonth%) do (
    if %%m leq 9 set month=0%%m
    if %%m gtr 9 set month=%%m
    if %%y equ %sy% if !month! leq %sm% (
        goto :continue
    )
    if %%y equ %ey% if !month! equ %em% (
        goto :breakloop
    ) else (
        call :DaysOfMonth %%y !month!
        set maxDay=!errorlevel!
        echo Days Of Month !month!: !maxDay!
```

Here's the full script:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set maxHour=23
set maxMonth=12
set missing=0

set /p sy="Enter start year (e.g. 2020): "
set /p sm="Enter start month (e.g. 08): "
set /p ey="Enter end year (e.g. 2020): "
set /p em="Enter end month (e.g. 08): "
set CUR_YYYY=%date:~10,4%
set CUR_MM=%date:~4,2%
set CUR_DD=%date:~7,2%
set CUR_HH=%time:~0,2%
if %CUR_HH% lss 10 (set CUR_HH=0%time:~1,1%)

set CUR_NN=%time:~3,2%
set CUR_SS=%time:~6,2%
set CUR_MS=%time:~9,2%

set SUBFILENAME=%CUR_YYYY%%CUR_MM%%CUR_DD%-%CUR_HH%%CUR_NN%%CUR_SS%
echo ***LIST OF MISSING FILES FROM %sm% %sy% to %em% %ey%*** > checkFile_%SUBFILENAME%.txt

for /L %%y in (%sy%,1,%ey%) do (
    for /L %%m in (1,1,%maxMonth%) do (
    if %%m leq 9 set month=0%%m
    if %%m gtr 9 set month=%%m
    if %%y equ %sy% if !month! leq %sm% (
        goto :continue
    )
    if %%y equ %ey% if !month! equ %em% (
        goto :breakloop
    ) else (
        call :DaysOfMonth %%y !month!
        set maxDay=!errorlevel!
        echo Days Of Month !month!: !maxDay!
        set missingMonth=0

        for /L %%d in (1,1,!maxDay!) do (
        if %%d leq 9 set day=0%%d
        if %%d gtr 9 set day=%%d
        for /f "tokens=1*" %%i in ('PowerShell -Command "& {Get-Date "!day!/!month!/%%y" -format "ddd_MMM_dd"}"') do (
            for /L %%f in (0,1,!maxHour!) do (
            if %%f leq 9 set hour=0%%f
            if %%f gtr 9 set hour=%%f
            if not exist "%%i_!hour!_00_00_%%y.enf" (
                echo Missing: %%i_!hour!_00_00_%%y.enf
                echo Missing: %%i_!hour!_00_00_%%y.enf >> checkFile_%SUBFILENAME%.txt
                set /A missing = missing+1
                set /A missingMonth = missingMonth+1
            )
            )
        )
        )
        )
    echo NUMBER OF FILES MISSING FOR !month!: !missingMonth!
    echo ***NUMBER OF FILES MISSING FOR !month!: !missingMonth!*** >> checkFile_%SUBFILENAME%.txt
    echo. >> checkFile_%SUBFILENAME%.txt
    :continue
    )
)
:breakloop
echo TOTAL NUMBER OF FILES MISSING FROM %sm% %sy% to %em% %ey%: %missing%
echo. >> checkFile_%SUBFILENAME%.txt
echo ***TOTAL NUMBER OF FILES MISSING FROM %sm% %sy% to %em% %ey%*** >> checkFile_%SUBFILENAME%.txt
pause

:DaysOfMonth Year Month
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set /a "yy = %~1, mm = 100%~2 %% 100"
set /a "n = 30 + !(((mm & 9) + 6) %% 7) + !(mm ^ 2) * (!(yy %% 4) - !(yy %% 100) + !(yy %% 400) - 2)"
endlocal &exit /b %n%
```

Comment: what is with the dots end of file? Also, is the else really on its own line without a open parenthesis? it should be `) else (` . That said, I gave you a working [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62949168/detecting-missing-file-using-batch-script) showing you exactly that, which you really never acknowledged because you were waiting on the powershell version.

Comment: Hi Gerhad,

The dots at the end of the file just indicate that there are more code which I have removed as those parts work as expected. They are more of for my own reference. For the else, I have brackets on my own code, most likely they have been accidentally removed by me which I was copying the codes over.

For the example which you have showed me, I have added them into my script and made some minor amendments as I realised that the **day** and the **month** in the powershell command were placed in the opposite way.

Comment: I have edited to show my full script. This is exactly what I have at the current point where the newly added for loop is causing some problem as the script breaks there.

Comment: ok, same story in the full script, `else` is on its own line. it has to be `) else (`. Else is not a command, if it is on a new line, then it will cause an error.

Comment: Another issue, your loop does `for /l %%y` but later in the `powershell` command you uppercase it to `%%Y` which is not the same metavariable.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for pointing out the error. However, I just tried, the script will break the moment it reaches the first for loop which uses %sy% and %ey% as the start value and stop value respectively. Do you know what's wrong with it?

Comment: no labels allowed within a code block. `goto :continue` breaks your loop(s) unintended.

Comment: Hi Stephan, thanks for your input. If that's the case, probably I have to rewrite the script to do away with the "Continue" and "Break" which batch does not have in its commands.

Comment: `goto` a label *outside* the loop is actually ok (to intentionally break the loop). Using it to break an inner loop and keeping the outer loop running doesn't work though. `goto` breaks *all* loops.

Comment: ... oh, and each `:label` (or `:: comment`) inside a loop/codeblock may cause severe headaches `;)`

Comment: 08 and 09 are not valid integers.  So the FOR command fails on that.

Comment: Thanks Stephan and Squashman for the input and advise. I guess this script needs a heavy rework then... Probably on the program workflow.